# Wavemon's EWMA returns garbage when used outside of wavemon

Tags: c, signal-processing

I have a novel wifi application that I'm building in C/C++ that requires me to calculate the ewma (exponentially weighted moving average) of the received wifi signal. Not being thoroughly versed in it's application, and lazy, I stole the ewma calculation out of wavemon.h:

```
double ewma(double avg, double sample, double weight)
{
   return avg==0 ? sample : weight*avg+(1.0-weight)*sample;
}
```

But, regardless of the input, this function only returns the garbage value 1069128089. All the samples I'm taking are in the range of 10^-3 to 10^-9, and I've tried weight at values from 0 to .5. `avg` is initialized in main to zero, and the samples do not undergo any sort of transformations before being sent into `ewma`.

Here's my main:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//custom headers
#include "sampling.h"
#include "pktdetection.h"

void main(int argc, char*argv[]){
        char *ifname={"wlan0"};
        char sec;
        int i, avg_flag=0;
        long samples=16;
        struct reading rdg;  //has two members: double pwr and char prefix
        double mavg=0,decay=0.1;

        i=0;
        while(i<samples)
        {
                rpt_pcket(dtct_pcket(ifname));//holds the thread until a packet is 
                                              //recieved
                rdg=get_sample(ifname);//samples the interface
                                                         //rx power returns watts
                mavg=ewma(mavg,rdg.pwr,decay);//<----weirdness here
                rdg.prefix=scale(&(rdg.pwr));//scaling and metric prefix
                put_sample(&rdg);// writes the sample to the screen
        }
}
```

Thank you for your help, I'm at the end of my tether.

Requested get_sample function, with all headers in the sampling.h:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <linux/wireless.h>
#include <tgmath.h>

struct reading get_sample(char* ifname)
{
        struct iw_statistics reading;
        int level, dbm;
        double power;
        struct reading sample;

        iw_getstat(&reading,ifname);
        level=reading.qual.level;
        dbm=u8_to_dbm(level);
        power=dbm2mw(dbm);
        sample.pwr=power;

        return sample;
}
```

Compiles, same as always as `gcc *.c -lm -o pwrsamp` and still returns garbage

Comment: Could you show a small snippet of how you use it?

Comment: Show how/where `rdg` values are assigned.

Comment: I had the same thought, but gdb showed that a reasonable value was being passed to ewma. Here it is, in case it helps: